# How can I programmatically make my TableView scroll down and bounce up?

Tags: swift, uitableview

When I tap a button, I'd like the TableView to scroll all the way to the top and bounce back down exactly as if the user has pulled all the way down and released. Is there a way to do this with code?

Answer (score 1):

Please You can Try With This:-

```
if (self.tableView.contentOffset.y >= (self.tableView.contentSize.height - self.tableView.bounds.size.height)) 
{
    // Don't animate
}
```

OR----

In todays times (Xcode 7), below code should solve most use cases since it accounts for UIScrollView (and it's subclasses UITableView and UICollectionView) insets, single storyboard for multiple devices (i.e. size classes) -

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if (Int(scrollView.contentOffset.y + scrollView.frame.size.height) == Int(scrollView.contentSize.height + scrollView.contentInset.bottom)) {
        if !isFetching {
            isFetching = true
            fetchAndReloadData(true)
        }
    }
}
```

You Check Both Way i think this is helpful for you. :-)